# Better way to write multiple sums with complicated indices

Tags: math-mode

Is there a way to display the indices of multiple series like that in a way that is clearer or easier to read? I am glad for any suggestions.

```
\documentclass{report}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
    & \sum_{\{j=1,\dots ,m\}}
      \sum_{\{p'\in X_{j}|s-l_{j}+1 \leq p' \leq s\}}
      \sum_{\{q'\in Y_{j}|t-w_{j}+1 \leq q' \leq t\}}
      \sum_{\{r'\in Z_{j}|u+1 \leq r' \leq H-h_{j}\}}
      \left( \frac{P_{j}}{l_{j}\cdot w_{j}} \right) 
      \cdot x_{jp'q'r'} \\[10pt]
    & \leq \sum_{\{i=1,\dots ,m\}}
      \sum_{\{p\in X_{i}|s-l_{i}+1 \leq p \leq s\}}
      \sum_{\{q\in Y_{i}|t-w_{i}+1 \leq q \leq t\}}
      \sum_{\{r\in Z_{i}|u-h_{i}+1 \leq r \leq u\}}
      \sigma_{i} \cdot x_{ipqr} \\[10pt]
    & \forall s\in X, t\in Y, u\in Z.
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i do not understand what mean this math expresion: `{\{p'\in X_{j}|s-l_{j}+1 \leq p' \leq s\}}`? do you like to say that p'\in X_{j}` and for indices of `p` are from domain: `s-l_{j}+1 \leq p' \leq s` ? can be this two part in two lines? welcome to tex.se!

Comment: the markup is more complicated than it need be, with split inside align, but also do you need multiple `\sum` can you not write it as a single summation and put all the ranges in a stack underneath (also use `\mid` not `|` to get better spacing for set expressions)

Answer (score 6):

Same idea as @David Carlisle's, with some improvements with `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
\sum_{\substack{
j=1,\dots ,m\\
\mathclap{p'\in X_{j},\: s-l_{j}+1 \leq p' \leq s}\\
\mathclap{q'\in Y_{j},\: t-w_{j}+1 \leq q' \leq t}\\
\mathclap{r'\in Z_{j},\: u+1 \leq r' \leq H-h_{j}}
}}\mkern-6mu
      \left( \frac{P_{j}}{l_{j}\cdot w_{j}} \right)
      \cdot x_{jp'q'r'}
     \leq\sum_{\substack{
i=1,\dots ,m\\
\mathclap{p\in X_{i},\: s-l_{i}+1 \leq p \leq s}\\
\mathclap{q\in Y_{i},\: t-w_{i}+1 \leq q \leq t}\\
\mathclap{r\in Z_{i},\: u-h_{i}+1 \leq r \leq u}
}}\mkern-12mu
      \sigma_{i} \cdot x_{ipqr} \\%[10pt]
    \forall s\in X, t\in Y, u\in Z.
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yep I was in a rush mathclap a definite improvement here:=)

Answer (score 5):

If I understood the expression correctly, can you not use a single summation?

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\sum_{\substack{
j=1,\dots ,m\\
p'\in X_{j}\mid s-l_{j}+1 \leq p' \leq s\\
q'\in Y_{j}\mid t-w_{j}+1 \leq q' \leq t\\
r'\in Z_{j}\mid u+1 \leq r' \leq H-h_{j}
}}
      \left( \frac{P_{j}}{l_{j}\cdot w_{j}} \right) 
      \cdot x_{jp'q'r'} 
     \leq\sum_{\substack{
i=1,\dots ,m\\
p\in X_{i}\mid s-l_{i}+1 \leq p \leq s\\
q\in Y_{i}\mid t-w_{i}+1 \leq q \leq t\\
r\in Z_{i}\mid u-h_{i}+1 \leq r \leq u
}}
      \sigma_{i} \cdot x_{ipqr} \\[10pt]
    \forall s\in X, t\in Y, u\in Z.
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{j=1}^m\
 \sum_{\substack{p'=s-l_j+1\\p'\in X_j}}^s\
 \sum_{\substack{q'=t-w_j+1\\q'\in Y_j}}^t\
 \sum_{\substack{r'=u+1\\r'\in Z_j}}^{H-h_j}
 \frac{P_jx_{jp'q'r'}}{l_jw_j}\\
&\leq\sum_{i=1}^m\
  \sum_{\substack{p=s-l_i+1\\p\in X_i}}^s\
  \sum_{\substack{q=t-w_i+1\\q\in Y_i}}^t\
  \sum_{\substack{r=u-h_i+1\\r\in Z_i}}^u
  \sigma_ix_{ipqr} 
  \quad\forall s\in X,\ t\in Y,\ u\in Z.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: from math point of view you the second sum is equal to `\sum_{p'\in X_j}` where `X_j=\{s-l+1, \dots, s\}` and can be written on the right side of equation. but i'm not sure, what op like to tell with used notation.